# How to convert shell script to arm executable binary for android?

Tags: android, shell, binary

Do anybody have an idea of how to convert a shell script to a binary that can be executed on arm cpu on android os? Something similar to shc. I have a pack of position dependent scripts and would like to 'hide' it's content - thats the main aim. I already tried to compile shc on arm cpu but created binary doesnt work. Any idea? Thanks in advance.